# iPad custom Keyboard GUI

Tags: iphone, ipad, keyboard

I want to create custom GUI for keyboard layout instead of normal layout. How can I achieve this?

Can anyone help me ?

Is there any built-in style/layout available or do I need to create a view for same?

Thanks,
Jayesh

Comment: Could you clarify whether you want to develop a custom keyboard or a custom text input field?

Answer (score 11):

You use the inputView property of a UITextField or UITextView. Simply assign it a custom view of your own. Then, when the receiver becomes the first responder, the system will automatically show your custom view as the keyboard. It will also hide it, when resigning first responder.

As far as I know, there are no templates.

Comment: That worked great!  I had to use NSBundle's loadNibNamed:owner:options (e.g., NSObject *obj = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"KeyboardEntry" owner:self options:nil]; and loop through the hierarchy to establish the view.  Now does anyone have any hints on writing the delegation protocol?

Comment: Be careful, because this works a little weird with split/undocked keyboard setting turned on :(

Answer (score 5):

I collected a view links about this topic with screenshots of keyboard-layouts + links about the programming-background. The article is in german but the links are all english: http://uxzentrisch.de/custom-mobile-keyboard-design/

Thanks for your answer, Jorge!