# How to set Custom keyboard specific to only a UItextfield

Tags: iphone, keyboard, uikeyboard

How to set Custom keyboard specific to only a `UITextField`? When I am changing [using this method](http://blog.demay-fr.net/2009/07/cocoa-how-to-add-a-toolbar-with-button-on-top-of-a-uitextview-in-order-to-add-a-dismiss-button/), all the keyboards in my application are changed to this new custom keyboard. I added:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self.view 
                                      selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) 
                                      name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
                                      object:nil];
```

in a `UIViewController`. But after going to that `UIView`, keyboards in other `UIViewController`s also look like new custom keyboard. How can i limit the custom keyboard to only one `UIView`? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was once am loading custom keyboard, it remains everywhere in other UIviews of application. So i checked existence of UIToolbar in other UIkeyboard subviews  and removed . Now its working fine..

```
    for(UIView* keyboardToolbar in [keyboard subviews]){
        if([[keyboardToolbar description] hasPrefix:@"<UIToolbar"] == YES)
            {
                [keyboardToolbar removeFromSuperview];      
            }
    }
```

Comment: instead of using hasPrefix to determine if an instance if of a particular class, use `isMemberOfClass:` or `isKindOfClass:`

Answer (score 4):

```
UITextField* textField;
UIView* customKeyboard;


textField.inputView = customKeyboard;
```

Similar thread: [iPad custom Keyboard GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558806/ipad-custom-keyboard-gui)

Answer (score 1):

If you subclassed UITextView (as that tutorial shows), then all instances of that subclass will use the toolbar with a dismiss button.

If you don't want the toolbar, then don't use the subclass, just use the original UITextView.

Comment: I am not subclassing UItextview. I used only that function keyboardWillShow and addObserver method  .Is it because i am using  for(UIWindow *keyboardWindow in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows])  ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try checking for the textfield that you want on the textFieldShouldBeginEditing like so:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == YOUR_DESIRED_TEXTFIELD) {
        [self openCustomKeyboard];
    }
    return YES;
}
```