# UIAlertView With Custom Keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, keyboard, uialertview

I have a **UITextView** added on my **UIView** programmatically. The textview added is not editable except one default **Textview** for entering the name, it is just to display some data.I m using My **Custom** Keyboard.After Some action I Have to Add player name.So I Using the **UIAlertview** With **UITextField** But when I  press on TextField It displays Default KeyBoard, instead Of default keyboard, I want to use My custom KeyBoard to enter the player name.I Already stop the become firstResponder For **textfield** of **AlertView**.I have no clue how to do this. Please give me some ideas.

Comment: Ask questions after searching properly.

Comment: @RandeepSingh I hope you meant the opposite :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610542/custom-iphone-keyboard

Comment: u guys can't get my point..I want to use custom keyboard with UIAlertView

Comment: did you craete a custom alert view with a uitextfield?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign a custom keyboard (UIView) to inputView property of your textfield.

You can check the following thread

[How to set Custom keyboard specific to only a UItextfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265363/how-to-set-custom-keyboard-specific-to-only-a-uitextfield)

or the following page

http://oneweekapp.com/a-custom-keyboard-the-easy-way/